# Upgrade Kills Query

Tags: neo4j

I'm testing upgrading neo4j from 3.0.4 to 3.4.7 and a query that previously returned in 321 ms now hangs and never returns.

I don't use any indexes or constraints.

The explain looks a bit different, but pretty similar

I can't post a profile because I've been waiting for about 3 hours for it to return....

It's a small install with about 50k records.

The data is genealogy data, so relationship heavy.  The variable length relationship part of the query is what slows it down in general and in this instance can have a length of up to 18.

I did a pretty minimal vanilla upgrade, I only had to change the upgrade and shell parameters in neo4j.conf to make it work.

Any ideas?

**3.0.4 Explain**

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ explain match (c:Person)-[:IS_WHAKAPAPA_FOR]->(tenant:Tenant)
> where tenant.id = 'TRONR' and not((:Person)-[:HAS_PARENT]->(c))
> match (t:Person)-[:IS_WHAKAPAPA_FOR]->(tenant)
> where t.tupunaId is not null
> with c, tenant, t
> match (c)-[:HAS_PARENT*]->(t)
> return count(c);
+--------------------------------------------+
| No data returned, and nothing was changed. |
+--------------------------------------------+
582 ms

Compiler CYPHER 3.0

Planner COST

Runtime INTERPRETED

+-----------------------+----------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| Operator              | Estimated Rows | Variables                                      | Other                             |
+-----------------------+----------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| +ProduceResults       |             13 | count(c)                                       | count(c)                          |
| |                     +----------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| +EagerAggregation     |             13 | count(c)                                       |                                   |
| |                     +----------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| +Expand(Into)         |            168 | anon[17] -- anon[135], anon[222], c, t, tenant | (c)-[:IS_WHAKAPAPA_FOR]->(tenant) |
| |                     +----------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| +AntiSemiApply        |            534 | anon[135], anon[222], t, tenant -- c           |                                   |
| |\                    +----------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| | +Filter             |           2835 | anon[89], anon[98], c                          | anon[89]:Person                   |
| | |                   +----------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| | +Expand(All)        |           2835 | anon[89], anon[98] -- c                        | (c)<-[:HAS_PARENT]-()             |
| | |                   +----------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| | +Argument           |           2134 | c                                              |                                   |
| |                     +----------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| +Filter               |           2134 | anon[135], anon[222], c, t, tenant             | c:Person                          |
| |                     +----------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| +VarLengthExpand(All) |           2134 | anon[222], c -- anon[135], t, tenant           | (t)-[:HAS_PARENT*]->(c)           |
| |                     +----------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| +Filter               |           1607 | anon[135], t, tenant                           | t:Person AND hasProp(t.tupunaId)  |
| |                     +----------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| +Expand(All)          |           3213 | anon[135], t -- tenant                         | (tenant)<-[:IS_WHAKAPAPA_FOR]-(t) |
| |                     +----------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| +Filter               |              0 | tenant                                         | tenant.id == {  AUTOSTRING0}      |
| |                     +----------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| +NodeByLabelScan      |              3 | tenant                                         | :Tenant                           |
+-----------------------+----------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+

Total database accesses: ?
```

**3.4.7 Explain**

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ explain match (c:Person)-[:IS_WHAKAPAPA_FOR]->(tenant:Tenant)
> where tenant.id = 'TRONR' and not((:Person)-[:HAS_PARENT]->(c))
> match (t:Person)-[:IS_WHAKAPAPA_FOR]->(tenant)
> where t.tupunaId is not null
> with c, tenant, t
> match (c)-[:HAS_PARENT*]->(t)
> return count(c);
+--------------------------------------------+
| No data returned, and nothing was changed. |
+--------------------------------------------+
2 ms

Compiler CYPHER 3.4

Planner COST

Runtime INTERPRETED

Runtime version 3.4

+-----------------------+----------------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Operator              | Estimated Rows | Variables                                      | Other                                |
+-----------------------+----------------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| +ProduceResults       |             13 | count(c)                                       |                                      |
| |                     +----------------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| +EagerAggregation     |             13 | count(c)                                       |                                      |
| |                     +----------------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| +Expand(Into)         |            168 | anon[135] -- anon[17], anon[222], c, t, tenant | (t)-[:IS_WHAKAPAPA_FOR]->(tenant)    |
| |                     +----------------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| +Filter               |            534 | anon[17], anon[222], c, t, tenant              | EXISTS(t.tupunaId); t:Person         |
| |                     +----------------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| +VarLengthExpand(All) |           1067 | anon[222], t -- anon[17], c, tenant            | (c)-[:HAS_PARENT*]->(t)              |
| |                     +----------------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| +AntiSemiApply        |            803 | anon[17], tenant -- c                          |                                      |
| |\                    +----------------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| | +Filter             |           4268 |   NODE89,   REL98, c                           | `  NODE89`:Person                    |
| | |                   +----------------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| | +Expand(All)        |           4268 |   NODE89,   REL98 -- c                         | (c)<-[  REL98:HAS_PARENT]-(  NODE89) |
| | |                   +----------------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| | +Argument           |           3213 | c                                              |                                      |
| |                     +----------------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| +Filter               |           3213 | anon[17], c, tenant                            | c:Person                             |
| |                     +----------------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| +Expand(All)          |           3213 | anon[17], c -- tenant                          | (tenant)<-[:IS_WHAKAPAPA_FOR]-(c)    |
| |                     +----------------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| +Filter               |              0 | tenant                                         | tenant.id = $`  AUTOSTRING0`         |
| |                     +----------------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| +NodeByLabelScan      |              3 | tenant                                         | :Tenant                              |
+-----------------------+----------------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+

Total database accesses: ?
```

**EDIT**
If I restrict the variable length query I can get a profile and compare it to the 3.0.4 version:
**3.0.4**

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ profile match (c:Person)-[:IS_WHAKAPAPA_FOR]->(tenant:Tenant)
> where tenant.id = 'TRONR' and not((:Person)-[:HAS_PARENT]->(c))
> match (t:Person)-[:IS_WHAKAPAPA_FOR]->(tenant)
> where t.tupunaId is not null
> with c, tenant, t
> match (c)-[:HAS_PARENT*]->(t)
> return count(c);
+----------+
| count(c) |
+----------+
| 40607    |
+----------+
1 row
630 ms

Compiler CYPHER 3.0

Planner COST

Runtime INTERPRETED

+-----------------------+----------------+-------+---------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| Operator              | Estimated Rows | Rows  | DB Hits | Variables                                      | Other                             |
+-----------------------+----------------+-------+---------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| +ProduceResults       |             13 |     1 |       0 | count(c)                                       | count(c)                          |
| |                     +----------------+-------+---------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| +EagerAggregation     |             13 |     1 |       0 | count(c)                                       |                                   |
| |                     +----------------+-------+---------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| +Expand(Into)         |            168 | 40607 |   23138 | anon[17] -- anon[135], anon[222], c, t, tenant | (c)-[:IS_WHAKAPAPA_FOR]->(tenant) |
| |                     +----------------+-------+---------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| +AntiSemiApply        |            534 | 40205 |       0 | anon[135], anon[222], t, tenant -- c           |                                   |
| |\                    +----------------+-------+---------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| | +Filter             |           2835 |     0 |   17514 | anon[89], anon[98], c                          | anon[89]:Person                   |
| | |                   +----------------+-------+---------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| | +Expand(All)        |           2835 | 17514 |   75233 | anon[89], anon[98] -- c                        | (c)<-[:HAS_PARENT]-()             |
| | |                   +----------------+-------+---------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| | +Argument           |           2134 | 57719 |       0 | c                                              |                                   |
| |                     +----------------+-------+---------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| +Filter               |           2134 | 57719 |   57719 | anon[135], anon[222], c, t, tenant             | c:Person                          |
| |                     +----------------+-------+---------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| +VarLengthExpand(All) |           2134 | 57719 |  115439 | anon[222], c -- anon[135], t, tenant           | (t)-[:HAS_PARENT*]->(c)           |
| |                     +----------------+-------+---------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| +Filter               |           1607 |     1 |   56432 | anon[135], t, tenant                           | t:Person AND hasProp(t.tupunaId)  |
| |                     +----------------+-------+---------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| +Expand(All)          |           3213 | 28216 |   28217 | anon[135], t -- tenant                         | (tenant)<-[:IS_WHAKAPAPA_FOR]-(t) |
| |                     +----------------+-------+---------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| +Filter               |              0 |     1 |       3 | tenant                                         | tenant.id == {  AUTOSTRING0}      |
| |                     +----------------+-------+---------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| +NodeByLabelScan      |              3 |     3 |       4 | tenant                                         | :Tenant                           |
+-----------------------+----------------+-------+---------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+

Total database accesses: 373699
```

**3.4.7**

```
neo4j> profile match (c:Person)-[:IS_WHAKAPAPA_FOR]->(tenant:Tenant)
       where tenant.id = 'TRONR' and not((:Person)-[:HAS_PARENT]->(c))
       match (t:Person)-[:IS_WHAKAPAPA_FOR]->(tenant)
       where t.tupunaId is not null
       with c, tenant, t
       match (c)-[:HAS_PARENT*1..10]->(t)
       return count(c);
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Plan      | Statement   | Version      | Planner | Runtime       | Time | DbHits | Rows |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| "PROFILE" | "READ_ONLY" | "CYPHER 3.4" | "COST"  | "INTERPRETED" | 4490 | 0      | 1    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

+-----------------------+----------------+---------+---------+-----------+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Operator              | Estimated Rows | Rows    | DB Hits | Cache H/M | Identifiers                                  | Other                                           |
+-----------------------+----------------+---------+---------+-----------+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| +ProduceResults       |             13 |       1 |       0 |       0/0 | count(c)                                     | 0.0; 3.4; 3.4                                   |
| |                     +----------------+---------+---------+-----------+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| +EagerAggregation     |             13 |       1 |       0 |       0/0 | count(c)                                     | 0.0                                             |
| |                     +----------------+---------+---------+-----------+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| +Expand(Into)         |            168 |    3449 |       4 |       0/0 | tenant, t, anon[135], anon[17], c, anon[222] | 0.0; (t)-[anon[135]:IS_WHAKAPAPA_FOR]->(tenant) |
| |                     +----------------+---------+---------+-----------+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| +Filter               |            534 |    3449 | 1347753 |       0/0 | tenant, t, anon[17], c, anon[222]            | 0.0; t:Person                                   |
| |                     +----------------+---------+---------+-----------+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| +VarLengthExpand(All) |           1067 | 1344304 | 2354092 |       0/0 | tenant, t, anon[17], c, anon[222]            | 0.0; (c)-[anon[222]:HAS_PARENT*..10]->(t)       |
| |                     +----------------+---------+---------+-----------+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| +AntiSemiApply        |            803 |   14602 |       0 |       0/0 | anon[17], c, tenant                          | 0.0                                             |
| |\                    +----------------+---------+---------+-----------+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| | +Filter             |           4268 |       0 |   13614 |       0/0 |   NODE89,   REL98, c                         | 0.0; `  NODE89`:Person                          |
| | |                   +----------------+---------+---------+-----------+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| | +Expand(All)        |           4268 |   13614 |   41830 |       0/0 |   NODE89,   REL98, c                         | 0.0; (c)<-[  REL98:HAS_PARENT]-(  NODE89)       |
| | |                   +----------------+---------+---------+-----------+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| | +Argument           |           3213 |   28216 |       0 |       0/0 | c                                            | 0.0                                             |
| |                     +----------------+---------+---------+-----------+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| +Filter               |           3213 |   28216 |   28216 |       0/0 | anon[17], c, tenant                          | 0.0; c:Person                                   |
| |                     +----------------+---------+---------+-----------+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| +Expand(All)          |           3213 |   28216 |   28217 |       0/0 | anon[17], c, tenant                          | 0.0; (tenant)<-[anon[17]:IS_WHAKAPAPA_FOR]-(c)  |
| |                     +----------------+---------+---------+-----------+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| +Filter               |              0 |       1 |       3 |       0/0 | tenant                                       | 0.0; tenant.id = $`  AUTOSTRING0`               |
| |                     +----------------+---------+---------+-----------+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| +NodeByLabelScan      |              3 |       3 |       4 |       0/0 | tenant                                       | 0.0; :Tenant                                    |
+-----------------------+----------------+---------+---------+-----------+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+

+----------+
| count(c) |
+----------+
| 3449     |
+----------+

1 row available after 4490 ms, consumed after another 0 ms
```

Comment: See if you can trim down your query and succeed in being able to PROFILE up to a certain point. Since you're suspecting variable-length expansion, try PROFILE ending with `RETURN c, tenant, t` before the expansion, and note any differences between the plans. Also you should have an index on :Tenant(id) to speed up the initial match.

Comment: how about just adding that index?

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  The index doesn't make any difference, there are only three :Tenant nodes.
I've managed to limit the variable length relationship bit of the query enough to get a profile, I'll add it to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort a workaround with help from the neo4j community page - https://community.neo4j.com/t/upgrade-kills-query/1889/5